# Discord.js - How to change style of Button

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is how I create and send the button:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    /* ... Checking Command ... */

    const actionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setStyle("PRIMARY")
        .setLabel("X")
        .setCustomId("test"));


    message.channel.send({ content: "Test", components: [actionRow] });
}
```

A blue Button appears in the chat, as expected.

This is my Button-Listener:

```
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "test") {
            //Before: console.log(interaction.component);

            interaction.component.setStyle("DANGER");

            //After: console.log(interaction.component);
        }
    }
});
```

Logging the component-object before and after `.setStyle("DANGER")` also reveals, that the style got changed from Primary to Danger successfully.

But in my Discord Client, the Style/Color didn't change, and ontop of that I am getting an error, saying that the interaction failed.

The style-property doesn't seem to be read-only: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton?scrollTo=style

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You updated the style only locally, you didn't send the changed component back to the Discord API.

To get rid of the error "This interaction failed", you need to [**respond**](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#responding-to-an-interaction) to the interaction. One way to respond is to use [`MessageComponentInteraction.update()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction?scrollTo=update), which updates the original message.

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "test") {

            // Change the style of received button component
            interaction.component.setStyle("DANGER");

            // Respond to the interaction,
            // and send updated component to the Discord API
            interaction.update({
                components: [
                    new MessageActionRow().addComponents(interaction.component)
                ]
            });

        }
    }
});
```

[image]

To make this work with multiple buttons, use the example below.

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        // Make this work only for certain buttons,
        // with IDs like switch_0, switch_1, etc.
        if (interaction.customId.startsWith("switch_")) {

            // Change the style of the button component,
            // that triggered this interaction
            interaction.component.setStyle("DANGER");

            // Respond to the interaction,
            // and send updated components to the Discord API
            interaction.update({
                components: interaction.message.components
            });

        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work with multiple buttons?

Comment: @K.KDesgins I have updated the answer accordingly, if you want to update all the buttons at once, just iterate `interaction.message.components` and change the style of every corresponding "switch" button to `"DANGER"`.

Answer (score 3):

For any future viewers who might be using Discordjs V14+ you can't edit the components directly anymore, so you need to recreate them in order to edit them. This is a solution I came up with that flips the color when clicked!

```js
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 15000 });
collector.on('collect', async i => {
  //loop through each action row on the embed and update it accordingly
  let newActionRowEmbeds = i.message.components.map(oldActionRow => {

    //create a new action row to add the new data
    updatedActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder();
    
    // Loop through old action row components (which are buttons in this case)
    updatedActionRow.addComponents(oldActionRow.components.map(buttonComponent => {

      //create a new button from the old button, to change it if necessary
      newButton = ButtonBuilder.from(buttonComponent)
      
      //if this was the button that was clicked, this is the one to change!
      if(i.component.customId == buttonComponent.customId){

        //If the button was a primary button then change to secondary, or vise versa
        if(buttonComponent.style == ButtonStyle.Primary){
          newButton.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        }
        else if (buttonComponent.style == ButtonStyle.Secondary){
          newButton.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        }
      }
      return newButton
    }));
    return updatedActionRow
  });
  
  // and then finally update the message
  await i.update({components: newActionRowEmbeds})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor improvements to the solution of @LachyLegend for easier use.

TypeScript:

```
function updateComponent<T extends MessageActionRowComponentBuilder>(interaction: MessageComponentInteraction, newButtonFunc: (component: T) => T, customId = interaction.customId): ActionRowBuilder<MessageActionRowComponentBuilder>[] {
    const indices = findComponent(interaction, customId);
    if (!indices) {
        return [];
    }

    const actionRows = interaction.message.components.map<ActionRowBuilder<MessageActionRowComponentBuilder>>((row) => ActionRowBuilder.from(row));
    newButtonFunc(actionRows[indices.actionRowIndex].components[indices.componentIndex] as T);

    return actionRows;
}

function findComponent(interaction: MessageComponentInteraction, customId: string): {actionRowIndex: number, componentIndex: number} | undefined {
    const actionRows = interaction.message.components;
    for (let actionRowIndex = 0; actionRowIndex < actionRows.length; ++actionRowIndex) {
        const actionRow = actionRows[actionRowIndex];

        for (let componentIndex = 0; componentIndex < actionRow.components.length; ++componentIndex) {
            if (actionRow.components[componentIndex].customId === customId) {
                return {
                    actionRowIndex,
                    componentIndex,
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```js
function updateComponent(interaction, newButtonFunc, customId = interaction.customId) {
    const indices = findComponent(interaction, customId);
    if (!indices) {
        return [];
    }

    const actionRows = interaction.message.components.map((row) => ActionRowBuilder.from(row));
    newButtonFunc(actionRows[indices.actionRowIndex].components[indices.componentIndex]);

    return actionRows;
}

function findComponent(interaction, customId) {
    const actionRows = interaction.message.components;
    for (let actionRowIndex = 0; actionRowIndex < actionRows.length; ++actionRowIndex) {
        const actionRow = actionRows[actionRowIndex];

        for (let componentIndex = 0; componentIndex < actionRow.components.length; ++componentIndex) {
            if (actionRow.components[componentIndex].customId === customId) {
                return {
                    actionRowIndex,
                    componentIndex,
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
const reply = await interaction.reply(messageContent);
const collector = reply.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.Button, time: 3_600_000 });

collector.on('collect', async (buttonInteraction) => {
    const newActionRows = updateComponent(buttonInteraction, (button) => button.setStyle(button.data.style === ButtonStyle.Success ? ButtonStyle.Danger : ButtonStyle.Success));
    // updateButton<ButtonBuilder>(...) or updateButton<TheBuilderYouOverride>(...) for TypeScript

    await reply.edit({
        content: buttonInteraction.message.content,
        components: newActionRows,
    });
    buttonInteraction.update({});
});
```