# Discord JS 14 - Update Button Style

Tags: discord.js

**Hey,**
I have a question. Since I now use Discord JS 14 & the Discord JS 13 method to edit the style of a button doesn't work, I want to ask here if someone has a solution.

This is how we did in it Discord.JS 13:

```
interaction.component.setLabel("Label")
interaction.update({
  components: interaction.message.components
});
```

I have tried many thing but couldn't find a solution so I want to ask here.

Comment: Do you mean `setStyle('PRIMARY')` etc doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Comment: Nope, I already have a button & wanna edit it. There was a way in DC JS 13 for that, but it doesn'tr work on DC JS 14 anymore.

Comment: ``` 
interaction.component.setLabel("Label")
                interaction.update({
                    components: interaction.message.components
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still search for a solution, but I found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73108750/13201553) to a question.

Long story short, you need to rebuild all buttons, as you no longer can update an already existing button's style.

For comparison, here's my old code for updating the clicked button's style to primary, and every others to secondary :

```js
const actionsRows = message.components.map((actionsRow) => ({
  ...actionsRow,
  components: actionsRow.components.map((button) => {
    const buttonStyle = button.customId === clickedButtonId
      ? 'SUCCESS'
      : 'SECONDARY';
    button.setStyle(buttonStyle);
    button.setDisabled(true);

    return button;
  }),
}));

message.edit({ components: actionsRows });
```

And here's the new code :

```js
const newActionRowEmbeds = message.components.map((oldActionRow) => {
  const updatedActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder();

  updatedActionRow.addComponents(
    oldActionRow.components.map((buttonComponent) => {
      const newButton = ButtonBuilder.from(buttonComponent);
      const buttonStyle = buttonComponent.customId === clickedButtonId
        ? ButtonStyle.Primary
        : ButtonStyle.Secondary;
      newButton.setStyle(buttonStyle);
      newButton.setDisabled(true);

      return newButton;
    }),
  );
  return updatedActionRow;
});

message.edit({ components: newActionRowEmbeds });
```